# TypeScript cannot find namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a web game using webGL, TypeScript and node. 
I have a file structure that currently looks like this

```
> node_modules
> src
   engine.ts
   webgl.ts
   index.ts
index.html
package.json
```

`engine.ts` looks like this:

```
namespace EngineSpace {
    export class Engine {
        // ....
    }
}
```

and `webgl.js`:

```
namespace EngineSpace {

    export class WebGLUtil {
       // .... 
    }
}
```

and `index.js`

```
window.onload = function() {
    let engine = new EngineSpace.Engine();
    engine.start();
}
```

However when I run `npm start`, I get that `src/index.ts:5:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EngineSpace'.`.

I am not sure why it cannot resolve this namespace. Given that I am trying to create a game, how should I have this set up / what would be best practices?

below is the `package.json:` file

```
{
  "name": "typescript-engine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:live",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "build:live": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

here is the `tsconfig:`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",                       
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "lib": ["es6","dom"],                    

    "outDir": "lib",                          
    "rootDir": "src",                         

    "strict": false,                       
   "esModuleInterop": true,                 

    "resolveJsonModule": true              
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your package.json and start script

Comment: I have added package.json

Comment: as I can see you are using `ts-node` to run the program I thought you want to run this on the web as you are using `window` object here.
You can't use window object in nodejs. Please do paste your tsconfig also

Comment: Ok. I have added that. If I am trying to get this to run in the browser, can I not still use node.js for my backend? How would you suggest setting up the project? I just want to make sure I get this part right.

Comment: If you want to run this on browser then you need to create a bundle of your project using any bundler tool like webpack.

Comment: You can use it for your backend. But the `window`-object is provided by the browser und you have no access to it in your backend.

Comment: Okay thats fair. So what am I missing in getting this running? Either way I am still not able to see the EngineSpace namespace from my index.ts. Node might even be more than what I need, but I want to be able to deploy nicely. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use namespace in nodejs side you need to export it also to use it in another module. Becuase namespace will be converted like this

`engine.ts`

```
namespace EngineSpace {
  export class Engine {
    public start() {
      console.log('hello');
    }
  }
}
```

`enigne.js`

```
var EngineSpace;
(function (EngineSpace) {
    class Engine {
        start() {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    }
    EngineSpace.Engine = Engine;
})(EngineSpace || (EngineSpace = {}));
```

And if you want to use some property of another module in nodejs you need to export it and need to require it in another module.

Refer this for nodejs [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html)

For the  browser setup with typescript please  refer [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/browser.html)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Ok thank you. The browser setup definitely helped. I'm just not sure where my engine file which describes `EngineSpace` namespace. Also, where do I put my `index.js` code i showed you? thanks.

Comment: you can keep the same structure, as browser don't have module options at the end it will be converted to single file

Comment: Interesting. I changed my entry in the webpack file to be index.tsx. However, it looks like now it does not know what EngineSpace is? Maybe I should put that back to the react file. How can I have my main.tsx run?

Comment: Are you creating the react project or a normal one?

Comment: I have downloaded the react setup, and replaced the webpack config to start at my index.tsx as opposed to their app.tsx. However it still does not like the EngineSpace thing. I want to have multiple files appending to the EngineSpace namespace by wrapping export class' in it. So I have a few files like: namespace EngineSpace { export class Thing {...} }. So I figured In my index.tsx I could just call EngineSpace.Thing()? But this is not working

Comment: Also, If I still wanted to use React, Is there a way to indicate where the javascript should start running for the Engine? because webpack will specify the entry point for the front end JS, but then that front end JS somehow needs to call the Engine code.

Comment: it will be great if you can give me some basic git project setup, so that I can see what is the problem properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201070/discussion-between-iamadeveloper-and-iza).